# Tensorflow 1.2 assigning variables

Tags: python, tensor, tensorflow

As the title says I'm using tensorflow version 1.2 built from source for my machine. I don't believe that affects my question though.

What is the difference between these two chunks of code?
The top one causes me to never get values assigned while training but the bottom does.  I am copying all my epoch data over to the gpu and then grabbing the data for each batch as I need it, so this code runs at the beginning of every batch inside the same session.

The code is in python and all of this is defined inside my model class.
All of the self.data objects are 3D float32 tensors.

```
    ## the index i.e the current step in the epoch
    index = tf.to_int32(self.step, name="step_to_int")

    ## code that doesn't work
    tf.assign(self.input_data, self.all_input_data[index])
    tf.assign(self.targets, self.all_target_data[index])

    ## code that works
    self.input_data = self.all_input_data[index]
    self.targets = self.all_target_data[index]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that pretty much everything is an operation in TensorFlow. I believe the issue in your code is that you never run the assignment operation (you just evaluate the `input_data` tensor as it has been initialised).

You then need to assign the return of the assignment method to a variable:

```
self.input_data = tf.assign(self.input_data, self.all_input_data[index])
```

This variable will hold both the new value and the reassignment operation, and so whenever you will evaluate it, it will update its value.

Quoting the doc string:

> Returns:
>       A `Tensor` that will hold the new value of 'ref' after
>         the assignment has completed.

Comment: Why does it work then when I do a sess.run(tf,assign(model.all_data, data)) ?   Also,  which is the "better" method to use?  tf.assign or just assigning it?

Comment: It works because you run the result of the `tf.assign`method which is an op holding the assign operation. I'll edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I switched it to assign the result of the tf.assign call and it works again.  Thanks.